# setTimeout and setInterval different

Tags: javascript

setTimeout and setInterval What is the difference between, for example, in the long-running function when the UI process?

```
  setTimeout(function(){
    /* Some long block of code... */
  }, 10);

  setInterval(function(){
    /* Some long block of code... */
  }, 10);
```

**If there is a long execution time, the execution time is greater than setTimeout or setInterval to set the time**

Comment: An interval runs periodically, a timeout runs once after a period of time.

Comment: You could end up with a race condition when using `setInterval` if the `long block of code` takes longer than the interval. If the code could take a while, you may be better off using `setTimeout`, and starting the next timer when the long code is finished.

Comment: @user1689607—javascript is single threaded, subsequent calls wont happen until the preceding call is finished. Too short an interval may tie up all resources though so the browser stops responding.

Comment: @RobG: Right, that's my point. Maybe "race condition" was the wrong term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setTimeout runs once and is good to use when you either

1. only want to run once
2. or runtime per call is variable and you
   need to have the call made sequentially

setInterval runs forever until you call clearInterval to cancel.

So, for long running process, it's good to use setTimeout and then have your setTimeout handler call setTimeout again to keep the loop running.

*EDIT*
The problem w/ setInterval is that if it takes longer than 10ms (in your case) to run then that next call can be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question, there is no difference besides the already mentioned one, both get the same priority.